# Drupal migrating cck int_phone field (6 to 7)

Tags: 7, entities

I'm trying to migrate the phone field type ('int_phone') that are in CCK fields from drupal6 to drupal 7 using the CCK migrate tool but I continuously get this error,

> Error creating field field_user_phone:
>   exception 'FieldException' with message 'Attempt to create a field of unknown type int_phone.' in D:\site\unops63\modules\field\field.crud.inc:110

Any idea why the error is coming. I could comment the error handling but I was thinking of a solution at this point.

Comment: Which module were you using in drupal 6 to provide the int_phone field?

Comment: I was using phone module and cck in drupal 6

Comment: Do you have the phone module installed in on your upgraded Drupal 7 site? The phone module has integration with the content migrate (cck) module so it should properly convert your field from int_phone to phone. Seems like possibly a bug in one of the modules you're using.

Comment: thanks for your comments rooby, but i have integrated the phone module and i have checked that its enabled yet the error comes. it seems as if field_info_field_types is not getting this as a field type.

Comment: I finished this by creating a new field in the system. then i used feeds to import the data from the old system to this one. this is just in case one is looking for a work around on this kind of issue.